# Code first foreign key association MVC Entity

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity

I have an Html sanitizer (more like an xss detector) code I'm working on and would like to log failures caused during code xss sanitation/detection.
So in entity, I have the following model for my UserProfile

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Security> SecurityViolations { get; set; } //is this correct???
}
```

and for my security class model, I have the following:

```
[Table("Security")]
public class Security
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string SecMsg { get; set; }
    public string Trace { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode{ get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; } 
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; } 
}
```

To clarify my idea, when a security failure happens, the Security model is filled in with information but I like to tie all that information to the user that generated the errors so I establish a foreign key relation (or try to at least), to the UserProfile UserId primary key column.

Therefore, the code to log to my Security table is as follows:

```
using (CCSecurity sec_db = new CCSecurity())
            {
                Security sec_execption = new Security();
                sec_execption.SecMsg = ex.Message;
                sec_execption.Trace = ex.StackTrace;
                sec_execption.UserId = uid;  //uid is 12, a PK entry in UserProfile
                try
                {
                    sec_db.Security.Add(sec_execption);
                    sec_db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace.ToString());
                }

            }
```

So then during one of my unit test execution, I get the following exception:

> "The property 'UserId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. 
>   The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. 
>   For collection properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid..."

I'm new to entity and googling the above turned many suggestion that did not solve my problem.
How can I have a foreign key in my Security class that references a primary key in my UserProfile class and still have it well documented in code (i.e the ForeignKey property field denotes foreign key in Security class) ?

**Edit:**

```
public class CCSecurity : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Security> Security { get; set; }
    public CCSecurity()
        : base("TBCdb")
    {}
}
```

**Edit 2**

The auto migration generated the Security Table as follow's:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Security] (
[Id]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[SecMsg]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Trace]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[ErrorCode] INT            NOT NULL,
[UserId]    INT            NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Security] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Security_dbo.UserProfile_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

);

Seem ok but it throws the error on SaveChanges():

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
>   "FK_dbo.Security_dbo.UserProfile_UserId". 
>   The conflict occurred in database \"TBCdb\", table \"dbo.UserProfile\",
>    column 'UserId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

[image]

**Latest Edit**
So I started a new project console app to test if something weird is happening on my main project. I basically copied my two models in the new project (Security and UserProfile) and got it to work... I'm using a file db and don't know what could be wrong in my main project and what can be different in the new console app project. I'm running a Unit Test on my main project and I wonder if that has anything to do with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message indicates, your foreign key needs to be associated with a valid entity property. So, instead of declaring the foreign key as follows:

```
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public int? UserId { get; set; }
```

You need to declare it as:

```
[ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

Comment: If I try your method, I get the following :"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Security_dbo.UserProfile_UserId\". 
The conflict occurred in database "TBCdb\", table \"dbo.UserProfile\", column 'UserId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated." The UserId I am referencing does exist in my UserProfile table. What else could I have setup wrog?

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because the use of the ForeignKey attribute. My stupid mistake was to not configure the connection on the Unit Test App.config . Once I entered the connection string there it all worked out fine. Too bad it took two days of debugging to get it to work :( Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need UserId property, just remove it and use UserProfile. Entity Framework will handle this automatically.

```
sec_execption.UserProfile = getUserProfileById(uid);
```

getUserProfileById might look like:

```
return sec_db.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == uid).FirstOrDefault();
```

P.S.

```
public virtual List<Security> SecurityViolations { get; set; } // is ok
```

but

```
public virtual ICollection<Security> SecurityViolations { get; set; } // is better
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but "sec_db.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == uid).FirstOrDefault();" belongs to Security. How can a UserProfile be obtained this way? See my edit where I posted the definition of CCSecurity.

Comment: Just add UserProfile to your context:

public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

Comment: ok so now I get "InnerException = {"Invalid column name 'UserProfile_UserId'."}" I don't get it, is it telling me its looking for a column named 'UserProfile_UserId' or 'UserId' in the table 'UserProfile'? The column does exist and my table does have a valid entry for the id I'm adding...

Comment: Also, "sec_db.UserProfile.Where(u => u.UserId == uid).FirstOrDefault()" is returning null...

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below to have one-to-many relationship between Users and Securtiy. As mentioned below **virtual** keyword is all required to indicate to EF a relationship between entities.

```
public class Security
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SecMsg { get; set; }
    public string Trace { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; } //This is just to tell EF to name the FK column as UserId rather than UserProfile_UserId

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; } //This is good enough to tell EF that there is a relationship
}

public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Security> Securities { get; set; } //Good enough to indicate the relationship
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did as you suggested but got another exception which I've seen many times before( please see my last edit). Thanks!

Comment: Above error indicates that you are inserting value under FK column in Security table which doesn't exist in UserProfile table's PK column. Please double check.

Comment: I would agree I'm doing something stupid... however, I'm inserting an Id of 12 which is Root(see the picture I added) "sec_execption.UserId = uid;  //uid is 12, a PK entry in UserProfile" code above. Any other suggestions?